# Can't open files after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: macos, finder

After upgrading from ML to Mavericks (MB Air, 13", 256GB, 2011) I can't open **any** file or folder from the standard Open menu from **any** app (except MS Office -2011). But, I can search for a file (and open it) if it has a label. All the files/folders are greyed out so can't select them, as it can be seen in the attached screen capture (from Preview.app).

If I try to save a file, the only place I can do that is in the default folder: if I try to change the folder (navigating through the Save box) I can't save it any more.

What I've done (nothing worked!):

1. repairing permissions
2. delete and create a new user (keeping the *user* folder in /Users)
3. updated to 10.9.1

It is worth to point out that this only happens in **my** user account: after discovering this situation I created a second admin user and everything works fine within it!

[image: This is a screenshot of the Open menu.]

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer below and accept it? This will make it easier for others to find it later.

Comment: You need to reset your Home Folder Permissions and ACLS in Reccovery Mode for the specified user account: http://pondini.org/OSX/Password.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James Payne stated, I did not solve the problem, instead I *deleted* it by re installing the SO. I couldn't try the solution proposed by njboot because I did it before his/her suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start by moving ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist (where ~ is you're home folder) to the desktop and restart the Finder by typing sudo killall Finder into terminal. If it works with another user, it may be something in you're Library folder that is causing the problem. I would also check you're startup items under System Preferences:Users:Login Items. Another thing that could help is check you're logs in the Console Application and see if it is reporting anything unusual there.

Comment: Thank you, but I solved this… by re-installing the SO…

Comment: Did you actually solve the problem or did you just delete the problem by reinstalling you're OS. Thanks for the vote down for trying to help.

Comment: I didn't vote down you! I am not such an a..h..le to do that to someone who's trying to help me!

Comment: Oh ok no worries. Somebody else must have. Just as a matter of interest, this actually happened to me once where I had bound my OSX account to a OS X OD server. To get my files back, I just unbound from the directory. Does that sound familiar?

Comment: Not at all! I just updated from 10.8.X to 10.9. And that was all!